# freemarker can't calling images of css

Tags: css, freemarker

my background images can't show, my directory structure is  like this

```
static
  -----images
  -----css
          ----btn.css
WEB-INF
  -----views
            ----ftl
                   ----index.ftl
```

the index.ftl use the btn.css

this is the index.ftl

```
  <link href="${BASE_PATH}/static/css/btn.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and this is the btn.css

```
.btn-box ul li.onmouse{ background: url(../images/90btn-on.jpg);}
```

but the jpg can't show in chrome, i change ie9,it's ok, what's the problem

Comment: What does Developer Console tell?

Comment: no information ,no error

Comment: Even after reload? Developer Console can't be empty after reload

Comment: why not ,there is no any information

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Do you have a link to the page?